# Graphviz: Rearrange Lines / Nodes

Tags: graphviz

I should use Graphviz to create a graph, which should look similar to this
[image: Graph]

Currently using this:

```
digraph Graph {
    // Nodes
    User [style=filled, color="#ff000055"]
    Kernel [style=filled, color="#ff000055"]
    Runnable [style=filled,color=dodgerblue]
    Swapping [style=filled,color=dodgerblue]
    Disk [style=filled, color=dodgerblue]
    Sleep [style=filled, color=dodgerblue]
    Lock [style=filled, color=dodgerblue]
    Idle [style=filled, color=dodgerblue]
    helpNode [style="invis"]

    // Edges
    User -> Kernel [dir=both,label = "mode switch"]
    Kernel -> Runnable [label = "preemption or time quantum expired"]
    Runnable -> Kernel [label = "schedule"]
    Runnable -> Swapping [label = "swap out"]
    Swapping -> Runnable[label = "swap in"]
    
    Kernel -> Disk
    Kernel -> Sleep
    Kernel -> Lock
    Kernel -> Idle
    Disk -> Sleep -> Lock -> Idle [style="invis"]

    
    // ranking
    {rank=same;Kernel;Runnable;Swapping}
}
```

to create this:

[image: Graph].

Is there any way to rearrange the nodes or lines?
Already tried something with Subgraphs and different types of ranking levels.

Comment: I'd put all the graph edges in (e.g. Disk->Runnable is missing) before trying to change the layout. Is this an assignment?

Comment: `Kernel -> Disk -> Runnable` etc. gives you the edges you want. Make it look more like the sample you provided will take a lot of tinkering but is possible.

Comment: @vaettchen wow i feel pretty dumb that i couldnt figure this out myself xD

Comment: Any idea how i can get a label on both sides of the lines?

Comment: Err, read the dotguide and docs https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html

Comment: Make it two instructions: `Kernel -> Disk[ label = "bla"]; Disk -> Runnable[ label = "blubb" ];`

Comment: Thats not what i meant. i mean on both sides of one line, like it is from User to Kernel.
I cant figure out how that works

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get pretty close to what you initially wanted, although the code looks ugly:

```dot
digraph G {

    // Defaults
    node [fontname="Arial", width=1.2, height=0.6, style="filled", fillcolor="#C2CEFF"]
    edge [fontname="Arial"]

    // Nodes
    User [fillcolor="#FFD2CD"]
    Kernel [fillcolor="#FFD2CD"]
    Runnable
    Swapping
    Disk
    Sleep
    Lock
    Idle

    // Comment 1
    User -> Kernel [label="running\n(on-CPU)", color="#FFFFFF00"]

    // Edges
    User -> Kernel [dir=both, label="  mode\n  switch", weight=10]
    Runnable -> Swapping [label="swap out"]
    Swapping -> Runnable [label="\nswap in"]
    Kernel -> Runnable [label="preemption or\ntime quantum expired", minlen=6]
    Runnable -> Kernel [label="\nschedule"]

    // Defaults for grid nodes
    node [shape="point", width=0.005, height=0.005, color="#000000"]

    // Grid nodes
    cn10 -> Disk [label="disk I/O"]
    cn11 -> Sleep [label="network I/O\nsleep"]
    cn12 -> Lock [label="block"]
    cn13 -> Idle [label="wait\nfor work"]
    cn10 -> cn11 -> cn12 -> cn13 [weight=10, dir=none]
    edge [dir=none]
    Disk -> cn20 [label="wakeup"]
    Sleep -> cn21 [label="wakeup"]
    Lock -> cn22 [label="wakeup"]
    Idle -> cn23 [label="work\narrives"]
    cn23 -> cn22 -> cn21 -> cn20 [weight=10, dir=none]

    // Connect grid nodes to the parent nodes
    Kernel -> cn10 [weight=10, dir=none]
    cn20 -> Runnable [weight=10, dir=forward]

    // Align center nodes
    Disk -> Sleep -> Lock -> Idle [style="invis"]

    // Comment 2
    Kernel -> cn13 [label="off-CPU", color="#FFFFFF00"]

    // Ranking
    rank = same { Kernel Runnable Swapping }
    rank = same { cn10 Disk cn20 }
    rank = same { cn11 Sleep cn21 }
    rank = same { cn12 Lock cn22 }
    rank = same { cn13 Idle cn23 }
}
```

[View in editor](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=digraph%20G%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Defaults%0D%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bfontname%3D%22Arial%22%2C%20width%3D1.2%2C%20height%3D0.6%2C%20style%3D%22filled%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23C2CEFF%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20edge%20%5Bfontname%3D%22Arial%22%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Nodes%0D%0A%20%20%20%20User%20%5Bfillcolor%3D%22%23FFD2CD%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Kernel%20%5Bfillcolor%3D%22%23FFD2CD%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Runnable%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Swapping%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Disk%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Sleep%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Lock%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Idle%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Comment%201%0D%0A%20%20%20%20User%20-%3E%20Kernel%20%5Blabel%3D%22running%5Cn%28on-CPU%29%22%2C%20color%3D%22%23FFFFFF00%22%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Edges%0D%0A%20%20%20%20User%20-%3E%20Kernel%20%5Bdir%3Dboth%2C%20label%3D%22%20%20mode%5Cn%20%20switch%22%2C%20weight%3D10%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Runnable%20-%3E%20Swapping%20%5Blabel%3D%22swap%20out%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Swapping%20-%3E%20Runnable%20%5Blabel%3D%22%5Cnswap%20in%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Kernel%20-%3E%20Runnable%20%5Blabel%3D%22preemption%20or%5Cntime%20quantum%20expired%22%2C%20minlen%3D6%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Runnable%20-%3E%20Kernel%20%5Blabel%3D%22%5Cnschedule%22%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Defaults%20for%20grid%20nodes%0D%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3D%22point%22%2C%20width%3D0.005%2C%20height%3D0.005%2C%20color%3D%22%23000000%22%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Grid%20nodes%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cn10%20-%3E%20Disk%20%5Blabel%3D%22disk%20I%2FO%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cn11%20-%3E%20Sleep%20%5Blabel%3D%22network%20I%2FO%5Cnsleep%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cn12%20-%3E%20Lock%20%5Blabel%3D%22block%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cn13%20-%3E%20Idle%20%5Blabel%3D%22wait%5Cnfor%20work%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cn10%20-%3E%20cn11%20-%3E%20cn12%20-%3E%20cn13%20%5Bweight%3D10%2C%20dir%3Dnone%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20edge%20%5Bdir%3Dnone%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Disk%20-%3E%20cn20%20%5Blabel%3D%22wakeup%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Sleep%20-%3E%20cn21%20%5Blabel%3D%22wakeup%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Lock%20-%3E%20cn22%20%5Blabel%3D%22wakeup%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Idle%20-%3E%20cn23%20%5Blabel%3D%22work%5Cnarrives%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cn23%20-%3E%20cn22%20-%3E%20cn21%20-%3E%20cn20%20%5Bweight%3D10%2C%20dir%3Dnone%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Connect%20grid%20nodes%20to%20the%20parent%20nodes%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Kernel%20-%3E%20cn10%20%5Bweight%3D10%2C%20dir%3Dnone%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cn20%20-%3E%20Runnable%20%5Bweight%3D10%2C%20dir%3Dforward%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Align%20center%20nodes%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Disk%20-%3E%20Sleep%20-%3E%20Lock%20-%3E%20Idle%20%5Bstyle%3D%22invis%22%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Comment%202%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Kernel%20-%3E%20cn13%20%5Blabel%3D%22off-CPU%22%2C%20color%3D%22%23FFFFFF00%22%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Ranking%0D%0A%20%20%20%20rank%20%3D%20same%20%7B%20Kernel%20Runnable%20Swapping%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20rank%20%3D%20same%20%7B%20cn10%20Disk%20cn20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20rank%20%3D%20same%20%7B%20cn11%20Sleep%20cn21%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20rank%20%3D%20same%20%7B%20cn12%20Lock%20cn22%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20rank%20%3D%20same%20%7B%20cn13%20Idle%20cn23%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

[image]